# Had Suddenly vs Gradually?

Tags: word-choice

> The honeybees had ___ vanished from their hives.
>
> a) Suddenly b) Gradually

This is a question I'm having a trouble solving. Which one is the correct answer to that blank? I think both of them are kind of right in that sentence, but it says only one of them is correct. Which is correct, and why would it be?

Comment: I agree with you. It is a bad question, if it is a grammar question. Was it possibly a reading comprehension question instead? For example, were you given a passage to read about honeybees, and then asked to answer some questions about it?

Comment: This is a bee question, not an English question. Both are correct grammatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many definitions of ***vanish*** define it as "to disappear, *especially quickly or suddenly*" (see, for example, [here](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/vanished)).

While it is true that "vanish" can be used to mean *gradually* disappear, this is not the *primary* sense. It is a *secondary* sense, according to many dictionaries.

If you expect the adverb to mirror the semantics of "vanish", "suddenly" is probably the correct answer. (For example, if this is primarily a vocabulary exercise related to "vanish", "suddenly" is probably correct).

But there is also a reason to think that "gradually" is the right answer. The fact that "suddenly" is encoded in the semantics of "vanish" makes the *overt* adverb "suddenly" redundant. Assuming redundancy is to be avoided, this supports the idea that "gradually" is the right answer. "Gradually" would need to appear overtly to defeat the mild connotation of "suddenly" encoded in the semantics of "vanish." I doubt, though, that an instructor who gave this question would expect students to reason all this out...

Comment: [See Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=suddenly+vanished%2C+gradually+vanished%2C+suddenly+disappeared%2C+gradually+disappeared&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csuddenly%20vanished%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgradually%20vanished%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csuddenly%20disappeared%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgradually%20disappeared%3B%2Cc0). Remarkably, it appears that *vanish* gradually took on the connotation *suddenly* over the last 150 years.

Comment: So 'suddenly vanish' has the primary reading 'suddenly suddenly disappear'.

Comment: "Vanish" has a sense of progressing from visible to invisible, as in a movie "fade".  In this sense it can be quick or protracted.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth, You're right that the fact that "suddenly" is encoded in the semantics of "vanish" makes the *overt* adverb "suddenly" redundant. This supports the idea that "gradually" is the right answer. "Gradually" would need to appear overtly to defeat the mild connotation of "suddenly" encoded in the semantics of "vanish." I doubt, though, that an instructor who gave this question would expect students to reason all this out... The question is bad. I've edited my answer.